# QGIS point displacement does not work as intended

Tags: qgis, point

Maybe I made a mistake, but I can't get it working. I have a CSV file with species-sightings and lot of them at the same locations. So to show all species I need to use point displacement. If I choose to show them categorized the outcome is as expected(pic 1), they are all over the map. But if I choose point displacement, all of them are around just one point (pic 2), that seems to be in the middle of the location (it's not the whole map in the pics).

It seems like I need to specify somehow the coordinates again? Or is it maybe a bug?

QGIS-Version: 2.14.3

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Comment: what units and value are you using for tolerance, is it mm / pixels / map units? If it's mm or pixels, this will vary according to zoom level and you might see this if you set the tolerance value too high. If it's map units and your CRS is in degrees, the tolerance will need to be a pretty small value.

Comment: that was the option I was looking for! thx, I just turned it off (0) and it worked like I wanted.. thank you very much!